# How to use "-replace" in Set-ADUser?

Tags: c#, powershell, replace

I want to use PowerShell via my C# to modify Active Directory attributes. Here is my PowerShell command which I can use to replace an Active Directory attribute:

```psh
Set-ADUser -Identity "kchnam" -Replace @{extensionAttribute2="Neuer Wert"}
```

How can I add the `@{extensionAttribute2="Neuer Wert"}` to my C# command?

My solution is not working:

```cs
Command setUser = new Command("Set-ADUser");
setUser.Parameters.Add("Identity", aduser);
string testadd = "@{extensionAttribute2=" + quote + "Neuer Wert" + quote + "}";
setUser.Parameters.Add("Replace", testadd);
```

Comment: `Hashtable testadd = new Hashtable{{"extensionAttribute2","Neuer Wert"}};`

Comment: Yes, it is working! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @PetSerAl Please add that as an answer, preferably with a short explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell that:

```
@{extensionAttribute2="Neuer Wert"}
```

means a `Hashtable` literal, not just `string`. So, in C# you also have to create a `Hashtable` object:

```
new Hashtable{{"extensionAttribute2","Neuer Wert"}}
```

Although, that is not fully equivalent to PowerShell, since PowerShell create `Hashtable` with case insensitive key comparer. But, very likely, that you can use any collection implementing `IDictionary`, not just a `Hashtable`.